# JSON not being appended

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

I'm not sure whats wrong, the script works fine in one file but fails to work in another in which Bootstrap Font-awesome are called via Bootstrap CDN and PureCSS is used as primary UX, vs stock CSS and jQuery. Frankly im lost since the code is the same, the designs are different but even so I have no clue why it aint being appended.

Here is the jQuery 1.6.2 based code (Im aware its old jQuery library)

```
$(document).ready(function) {

      $.getJSON( 'file.php?path=<?php echo $_GET['path']; ?>&jsoncallback=?', function( data ) {
      $("#content").html('');

      $.each(data, function (i, item) {

            $("#content").append('<div class="pure-u-1-5"><div class="product" data="' + item.path + '"><div class="like"></div><img src="assets/empty-0.gif" width="244" height="238" style="display:block;width:244px;height:238px;overflow:hidden;background-image:url(' + item.thumb + ');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top center;background-size:auto;"/><div class="title">' + item.name + '</div><div class="description"></div>&nbsp;<strong>Filesize:</strong> ' + item.size + '<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div>&nbsp;about ' + item.date + ' ago<div style="clear:both;height:8px;"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div></div>');

      });

      });

 });
```

Now here is the PHP portion as you see in $.getJSON call.

```
$dh = opendir($dir);
$files = array();
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    if ($file != '.' AND $file != '..' ) {
        if (filetype($dir . $file) == 'file') {
            $files[] = array(
            'id' => $file_id,
                'name' => $file_name,
                'size' => $file_size. ' bytes',
                'date' => time_since(date("ymd Hi", filemtime($dir . $file))),
                'path' => $dir . $file,
                'thumb' => . $dir . $file . "_th.jpg"
            );
        }            
    }
}
closedir($dh);

    $json = json_encode($files);

$callback = $_GET['callback'];
echo $callback.'('. $json . ')';
```

Based on source code the $_GET['path'] is being passed and appropriate folder path JSON file is being generated if you go to file.php in the browser. But its not being appended to #content

CSS snippt

```
<div class="databox">
     <div class="pure-g-r">
     <div class="pure-u-1">
          <div id="content"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions whats wrong? As again code works fine on different file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the content is appended but remains invisible due to styling.

Comment: There is one too many `</div>s` in the appended content.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot i have removed extra div from .append statement, however its still not being resolved. In regards to styling there are no elements being hidden, instead I'm calling 1-5 (5 grids). As mentioned before it all works fine with handmade CSS style, however using PureCSS + Font awesome combo seems to make the script not work. I tried appending the JSON response from Flickr and Picasa API's and they function just as needed, but not local JSON. And as mentioned before the local script responsible for outputting JSON works if visited directly.

Comment: Meme, something odd is going on, which I can't explain. You need a strategy to resolve the issue. eg, get something simple working by injecting client-side derived markup then work backwards - serve the same markup as a JSON response - then further migrate back to your original JSON. Discover at which point it breaks. One other thing - check the !DOCTYPE is correct.

Comment: Hi i think you better to use any jQuery plugin to append to the div. plugin like jPut(plugins.jquery.com/jput/). try with this its simple.